# An equation in floor function with two variables

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let us consider the following equation with respect to $x$ and $y$:

$$⌊x⌋=⌊y⌋$$

My **question** is how to obtain the unknowns $x$ and $y$. I have no idea to start.

Comment: They cannot be uniquely defined from only this equation. Any two numbers that have the same integer part (before the decimal point) works as a pair of solutions.

Comment: Since this equation does not have a unique solution, it would help if you say where you encountered it. If you came up with is yourself, then @MattiP. 's comment answers your question (making it an answer and not a comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. We could have $x = 2, y = 2.9$. Or we could have $x = 10034.7$ and $y = 10031 + \pi$. Or any number of other possibilities.

All we can tell from $\lfloor x\rfloor = \lfloor y \rfloor$ is that there is some integer $n$ such that $x, y\in [n, n+1)$.